# Select text of a particular shading color (VBA macro)

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight, shading

I am trying to use a macro to select text of particular shading in word ( I later want to change that shading and highlight it rather).

I are having trouble in selecting text of a particular shading color.

Using

char.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor <> wdColorAutomatic

works, selecting characters of any shading other than automatic, but using

char.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow

does not work. I want to be able to select text with a particular shading color. Any ideas as to why this isn't working or what might work rather?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that "Shading" has `ForegroundPatternColor` as well as `BackgroundPatternColor`. If you change only the *Pattern* settings in the *Shading* dialog box, then checking the `BackgroundPatternColor` will return wdColorAutomatic. If you change the *Fill* setting, then `BackgroundPatternColor` will return the color.

If you want to return a color for the *Pattern* section, then check `ForegroundPatternColor`, instead. Or both...